# Cycle through open Windows applications

Tags: windows, vbscript

I need some help on which way to go with something that seemed at first like a very simple requirement.

I have to find a method of cycling through open applications on a Windows PC, with the objective of displaying the windows for say 30 seconds at a time on a large screen mounted on a wall. Typically there will be an MS Access report and a couple of web pages.

My initial thinking was that I could open these apps manually on the PC, then run a VBScript to cycle through them. However there were two problems with this.

1. Simulating the Alt+Tab keypress just toggles the two most
   recently used apps instead of cycling through them all, and
2. There is no possibility I can see for the user to be able to
   escape out of the script using a keypress.

Can anyone suggest how I can achieve this using resources already available on a Windows (XP upwards) machine?

Comment: which version of windows is this aimed at?

Comment: Use [`Alt+Esc`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.03.windowsconfidential.aspx) instead of `Alt+Tab`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turned out VBScript in WHS was the way to go. This seems to work.

```
    '****************************************************************************************
' Script Name: ApplicationCycler.vbs
'      Author: Ian Burns
'        Date: 2 Dec 2011
' Description: VBScript for Windows Scripting Host. Cycles through any applications 
'              visible in the Task Bar giving them focus for a set period.
'       Usage: Save file to Desktop and double click to run. If it isn't already running,
'              it will start. If it is already running, it will stop.
'*****************************************************************************************
Option Explicit

Dim wshShell
Dim wshSystemEnv
Dim strComputer
Dim objWMIService
Dim colProcessList 
Dim objProcess
Dim intSleep

' Loop lasts 5 seconds
intSleep = 5000

Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
' Volatile environment variables are not saved when user logs off
Set wshSystemEnv = wshShell.Environment("VOLATILE")

' Check to see if the script is already running
If len(wshSystemEnv("AlreadyRunning")) = 0 Then

    ' It isn't, so we set an environment variable as a flag to say the script IS running
    wshSystemEnv("AlreadyRunning") = "True"

    ' Now we go into a loop, cycling through all the apps on the task bar
    Do
        ' Simulate the Alt+Esc keypress
        wshShell.SendKeys "%+{Esc}"
        Wscript.Sleep intSleep
    Loop

Else

    ' It IS already running so kill any or all instances of it
    strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'WScript.exe'")
    For Each objProcess in colProcessList
        objProcess.Terminate()
    Next

    ' Delete the environment variable
    wshSystemEnv.Remove("AlreadyRunning")

    ' Tidy up
    Set wshSystemEnv = Nothing
    Set wshShell = Nothing
    Set objWMIService = Nothing
    Set colProcessList = Nothing

End If
```

Comment: This solution has a major flaw in its logic. The "off" segment (the `Else` block) terminates itself before deleting the "AlreadyRunning" environment variable which blocks the script from running again until the user logs off. A quick fix would be moving the `wshSystemEnv.Remove("AlreadyRunning")` statement to the top of the `Else` block (prior to the WMI loop), though this is not an optimal solution since neither iterations (on/off) of the script will ever reach the `tidy up` segment.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, here's a "cleaner" solution (check my comment on the proposed solution) based on Ian Burns' script:

```
'****************************************************************************************
' Script Name: ApplicationCycler.vbs
'      Author: Ian Burns
'        Date: 2 Dec 2011
'   Edited By: Makaveli84
'   Edit Date: 30 Aug 2014
' Description: VBScript for Windows Scripting Host. Cycles through any applications 
'              visible in the Task Bar giving them focus for a set period.
'       Usage: Save file to Desktop and double click to run. If it isn't already running,
'              it will start. If it is already running, it will stop.
'*****************************************************************************************
Option Explicit

Dim wshShell
Dim wshSystemEnv
Dim intCycle
Dim intSleep
Dim intTimer

' Cycle every 5 seconds / Check on/off status every 250 milliseconds
intCycle = 5000: intSleep = 250: intTimer = intCycle

Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
' Volatile environment variables are not saved when user logs off
Set wshSystemEnv = wshShell.Environment("VOLATILE")

' Check to see if the script is already running
If len(wshSystemEnv("AlreadyRunning")) = 0 Then

    ' It isn't, so we set an environment variable as a flag to say the script IS running
    wshSystemEnv("AlreadyRunning") = "True"

    ' Now we go into a loop, cycling through all the apps on the task bar
    Do While len(wshSystemEnv("AlreadyRunning")) > 0
        ' Simulate the Alt+Esc keypress
        If intTimer >= intCycle Then
            wshShell.SendKeys "%+{Esc}"
            intTimer = 0
        End If
        intTimer = intTimer + intSleep
        Wscript.Sleep intSleep
    Loop

Else
    ' Delete the environment variable
    wshSystemEnv.Remove("AlreadyRunning")
End If


' Tidy up
Set wshSystemEnv = Nothing
Set wshShell = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

It's late and I did need a way to turn this excellent solution on and off manually.
Therefore, tested on xp Pro sp3:

```
'****************************************************************************************
' Script Name: Turn ON Loop thru open apps.vbs
'      Author: Ian Burns
'        Date: 2 Dec 2011
' Description: VBScript for Windows Scripting Host. Cycles through any applications 
'              visible in the Task Bar giving them focus for a set period.
'       Usage: Save file to Desktop and double click to run. If it isn't already running,
'              it will start. If it is already running, it will stop.
'*****************************************************************************************

' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356046/cycle-through-open-windows-applications

Option Explicit

Dim wshShell
Dim wshSystemEnv
Dim strComputer
Dim objWMIService
Dim colProcessList 
Dim objProcess
Dim intSleep

' Do Loop lasts 5 seconds
intSleep = 5000

Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
' Volatile environment variables are not saved when user logs off
Set wshSystemEnv = wshShell.Environment("VOLATILE")

If len(wshSystemEnv("AlreadyRunning")) = 0 Then

    ' It isn't, so we set an environment variable as a flag to say the script IS running
    wshSystemEnv("AlreadyRunning") = "True"

    ' Now we go into a loop, cycling through all the apps on the task bar
    do
        ' Simulate the Alt+Esc keypress
        wshShell.SendKeys "%+{Esc}"
        Wscript.Sleep intSleep
    loop

    ' Tidy up
    Set wshSystemEnv = Nothing
    Set wshShell = Nothing
    Set objWMIService = Nothing
    Set colProcessList = Nothing

End If

and:

'****************************************************************************************
' Script Name: Turn OFF Loop thru open apps.vbs
'      Author: Dave
'        Date: 1 Mar 2012
' Description: Turns off the above.
' '*****************************************************************************************
Option Explicit

Dim wshShell
Dim wshSystemEnv
Dim strComputer
Dim objWMIService
Dim colProcessList 
Dim objProcess
Dim intSleep

Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
' Volatile environment variables are not saved when user logs off
Set wshSystemEnv = wshShell.Environment("VOLATILE")

    ' It IS already running so kill any or all instances of the above
    strComputer = "."

    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & _
                        "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
                        strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

    Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
                           ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'WScript.exe'")

    For Each objProcess in colProcessList
        objProcess.Terminate()
    Next

    ' Delete the environment variable
    wshSystemEnv.Remove("AlreadyRunning")

    ' Tidy up
    Set wshSystemEnv = Nothing
    Set wshShell = Nothing
    Set objWMIService = Nothing
    Set colProcessList = Nothing
```