# Which Window Is Active

Tags: vba, excel

I have a short macro that places a cell in edit mode using the command:

```
Application.SendKeys "{F2}"
```

The line of code runs properly if the macro is run from the worksheet using, say,  the normal Ribbon interface *(that is because <kbd>F2</kbd> puts the active cell into Edit Mode)*

If I run the macro from the *VBE* window, the macro fails because the *VBE* interprets <kbd>F2</kbd> to be a command to bring up the Object Browser.

I want to include a test in the macro to check for this:

If the worksheet is the active window, proceed running.
If the VBE is the active window, then issue a warning MsgBox and abort.

I don't know how to determine which window is active.  `ActiveWindow.Caption` always displays something like:

```
Book1.xlsm
```

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33266859/vba-copypastecode-with-sendkeys/33269447#33269447

Comment: Will the value in the cell have changed if the worksheet is active. Can you check for a change? Instead of using SendKeys, could you use an InputBox instead?

Comment: @ScottCraner  The idea is good, but it still leaves the *VBE* window in focus................Rodger's method works!

Comment: @DougGlancy  First, thank you for responding...............Rodger's method suits my needs........since I need the SendKeys to get to the worksheet, I don't mind excusing the *VBE* window.

Comment: Yes, that's a good one. I saw it while googling, but didn't know if it was okay for the VBE to stay open.

Comment: @DougGlancy  An interesting point! ............although Rodger did not **exactly** answer my question, he did solve my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you ran into a VBE issue unfortunately. If the solution is to avoid making mistakes while coding, will this work for you? It doesn't appear that there is a way to see if the activewindow is the VBE that I could find. If this solution won't meet your needs, [Using VBS in WHS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356046/cycle-through-open-windows-applications) might work for you or calling an external program like autoit.

Note that it won't work if you are stepping through the code but I assume that you are really mainly concerned about hitting the run button from within the VBE window and it will work for that. Put the first line at the top of your code or right before the section with sendkeys or whatnot.

```
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False
If ActiveWindow.Caption <> "Book1.xlsm" Then MsgBox ("Test") Else MsgBox ("testelse")
```

You won't be able to alt-tab back, have to hit Alt-F11

Comment: Thank you very much................I will test this later today...................

Comment: This works to perfection!  I don't need to perform any testing, just close the *VBE* window.......................Thanks again!